# Как переопределить player.images

Tags: python, pygame, pgzero

Помогите пожалуйста, я уже много часов сижу над тем, как переопределить player.images. Всё никак не работает и ничего не подходит. Пишу игру на pgzero + использую pgzero helper. Это просто питон файл, который должен лежать в папке с вашим проектом. Скачать можно от сюда: https://github.com/QuirkyCort/pgzhelper
От туда вам понадобится только 1 файл pgzhelper.py
Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии стрелки влево, игра отрисовывала картинки для левой хотьбы. Помогите пожалуйста

Теперь прикрепляю код:

```
import pgzrun
import time
from pgzhelper import *


TITLE = "Arkanoid"
WIDTH = 1500
HEIGHT = 700



enemy = Actor("enemy1.png")
enemy.pos = (1400, 540)
enemy.images = ['enemy1.png','enemy2.png','enemy3.png','enemy4.png','enemy5.png','enemy6.png']
enemy.fps = 10



#Player
leftOrRight = False
player = Actor("stay.png", anchor=('left', 'center'))
player.pos = (50, 540)
rightt = ['walk1','walk2','walk3','walk4','walk5','walk6']
player.images = rightt
print(player.images)


player.fps = 30

player_speed = 5  # Скорость движения персонажа



#EndPlayer

bullet_speed = 10
bullet = Actor("bullet.png", anchor=('left', 'center'))
bullets = []


checkSkill = False
skill = Actor('skillready.jpg')
skill.pos = (30, 30)


bullet_cooldown = 0.5  # Время в секундах между выстрелами
last_bullet_time = time.time()

last_Megabullet_time = time.time()
megabullet_cooldown = 5.0


a = 0
kd = 5


#прыжок
velocity = 0 # Как быстро персонаж будет перемещаться вверх
gravity = 1 # гравитация



def draw():
    screen.blit("backg.jpg", (0, 0))   
    player.draw() 
    skill.draw()
    enemy.draw()
    for i in bullets:
        i.draw()

    if checkSkill == True:
        skill.image = 'skillready.jpg'
    elif checkSkill == False:
        skill.image = 'skillkd.jpg'
        screen.draw.text(str(kd), (50, 50), color="white", fontsize=40)



def update():
    global bullets, last_bullet_time, last_Megabullet_time, a, checkSkill, velocity
    #enemy
    enemy.animate()
    enemy.x -= 5

    print(player.images, "из update")
    if enemy.x <= 0:
        enemy.x = 1400

    #end_enemy

    current_time = time.time()
    if current_time - last_Megabullet_time > megabullet_cooldown:
        checkSkill = True


    if keyboard.left:
        print(player.images, "из left")
        player.animate()
        player.x -= player_speed
    

    
    elif keyboard.right:
        print(player.images, "из right")
        player.animate()
        player.x += player_speed

    
    elif keyboard[keys.SPACE]:
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - last_bullet_time > bullet_cooldown:
            player.image = "attack2.png"
            bullet = Actor("bullet.png", anchor=('left', 'center'))
            bullet.pos = (player.x + 50, player.y)  # Позиция пули относительно изображения персонажа
            bullets.append(bullet)
            last_bullet_time = current_time
            sounds.shot.play()
    

    elif keyboard.rshift:
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - last_Megabullet_time > megabullet_cooldown:
            checkSkill = True
            player.image = "attack2.png"
            sounds.megashot.play()
            delay = 1.45  # Задержка увеличивается с увеличением индекса
            clock.schedule(start, delay)
            last_Megabullet_time = current_time
            a = 0
            
    
    else:
        player.image = "stay.png"

    for i in bullets:
            i.x += bullet_speed
            if i.right > WIDTH:
                bullets.remove(i)

    if keyboard.up and player.y == 540:
        velocity = -10
    player.y += velocity
    velocity += gravity

    #Остановить падение зомби c экрана
    if player.y > 540:
        velocity = 0
        player.y = 540



def start():
    clock.schedule_interval(spawn_bullet, 0.1)
    #clock.unschedule(spawn_bullet)

def minusKd():
    global kd
    if kd >= 1:
        kd -= 1
    else:
        kd = 5

def spawn_bullet():
    global bullets, a, checkSkill
    if a == 10:
        clock.unschedule(spawn_bullet)
    else:
        bullet = Actor("bullet.png", anchor=('left', 'center'))
        bullet.pos = (player.x + 50, player.y)
        bullets.append(bullet)
        player.x -= 3
        a += 1
        checkSkill = False
        

# def animate_left():
#     player.image = player_images_left.pop(0)
#     player_images_left.append(player.image)

# def animate_right():
#     player.image = player_images_right.pop(0)
#     player_images_right.append(player.image)


if checkSkill == False:
    clock.schedule_interval(minusKd, 1.0)



music.play("musicback.mp3")
music.set_volume(0.1)

pgzrun.go()
```